# fb ui feed with different picture

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to change the picture location for different image as a share button, can this be done? or is there a better way to do it? and please inform me where do I start with function(){, I am completely new to javascript, looking for solution fore few days but...

my code in  show below

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'appid',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.0'
    });



                    FB.ui(
  {
   method: 'feed',
   name: 'The Facebook SDK for Javascript',
   caption: 'Bringing Facebook to the desktop and mobile web',
   description: (
      'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
      'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
      'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
   ),
   link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/',
   picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/public/f8.jpg'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);







  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

and my image code

```
<img src="uploads/intro/item01.png" width="65%" style="margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 18px;border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);padding-bottom: 15px;" onclick="postToFeed()" >
```